# Android: drawing a canvas to a view

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-bitmap

I am trying to draw a canvas that contains a circle to a view that was defined previously via findViewById() like this

```
    View v = findViewById(R.id.view1);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    c.drawCircle(v.getMeasuredWidth() / 2, v.getMeasuredHeight() / 2, v.getMeasuredWidth() / 4, paint);
    v.draw(c);
```

but there is no circle drawn to the view

My whole activity:

```
package com.burrlieexample.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class InstructionsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("DEBUG", "InstruciotnActivity");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_instructions);

        Button okay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        okay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        Log.d("DEBUG", "onFocusChanged");
//im doing this stuff in onWindowfocusChanged because getWidth returns 0 in onCreate
        View v = findViewById(R.id.view1);
        Log.d("DEBUG", "" + v.getMeasuredWidth() + ", " + v.getMeasuredHeight());
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        c.drawCircle(v.getMeasuredWidth() / 2, v.getMeasuredHeight() / 2, v.getMeasuredWidth() / 4, paint);
        v.draw(c);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and the View is in my layout xml file like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D0F3FF"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.burrlieexample.test.InstructionsActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:background="#00455F"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:text="Ok!" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/okButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So when the Activity starts the only things i see are the button and the background of my relative layout

Comment: read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html and this: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 4):

do this as simple :
    Drawing a circle to  View
                    Drawing to view is a better option when your UI does not require dynamic changes in the application.
                   This can be achieved simply by extending the View class and define an onDraw() callback method. Inside your View component's onDraw(), use the Canvas given to you for all your drawing, using various Canvas.draw...() methods (Ex: canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);). onDraw() is a callback method invoked when the view is initially drawn.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(new MyView(this));
     }

     public class MyView extends View {
         public MyView(Context context) {
              super(context);
              // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         }

         @Override
         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            int x = getWidth();
            int y = getHeight();
            int radius;
            radius = 100;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
            canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: 1) no `super.onDraw()` needed, 2) dont allocate any Objects in `onDraw` method, 3) why that strange habit of using `Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C")`?

Comment: thanks for the solution, but when im doing it this way than i cant use my button anymore right? because i set the content view to my view v, and only to my view v. Iwanted it a bit mixed, so that i have have a layout with a button and a view in it to which i can draw the canvas

Comment: And how would one accomplish this within a fragment @pskink?

Answer (score -2):

You fed a bitmap to the garbage collector. You never drew anything on the view. Consequently, nothing was drawn on the view.